# organize urls in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I have a problem with my urls, first of all here my urls.py:

```py
from .views import (
    CouponListView, CouponDetailView, buy_coupon, UserCouponListView, CouponOnResaleCreateView,
    CouponOnResaleListView,
) 

from django.urls import path

coupons_patterns = ([
    path('', CouponListView.as_view(), name = 'list'),
    path('<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', CouponDetailView.as_view(), name = 'detail'),
    path('create/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', CouponOnResaleCreateView.as_view(), name = 'create'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', UserCouponListView.as_view(), name = 'user'),
    path('coupon/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/buy/', buy_coupon, name = 'buy_coupon'),

], 'coupons')
```

Well, I want to add another "pattern" of urls so to speak, that is, the "pattern" of urls that I have is: `coupons:name` and I want to add one like this: `coupons_on_resale:name`, but without having to create another app.

How should I do it? It occurs to me to create other patterns like the one I showed before and include it, but is it good practice? Are there other ways?

I want a scalable, clean and easy to maintain structure in my urls.

---

**Update::**

It occurred to me this way, but it does not convince me much:

```
from .views import (
    CouponListView, CouponDetailView, buy_coupon, UserCouponListView, CouponOnResaleCreateView,
    CouponOnResaleListView,
) 

from django.urls import path, include

coupons_patterns = ([
    path('', CouponListView.as_view(), name = 'list'),
    path('<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', CouponDetailView.as_view(), name = 'detail'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', UserCouponListView.as_view(), name = 'user'),
    path('coupon/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/buy/', buy_coupon, name = 'buy-coupon'),

    path('resale/', include(([
        path('create/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', CouponOnResaleCreateView.as_view(), name = 'create'),

    ], 'resale')))

], 'coupons')
```

Thanks for your suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to structure my urls in a way that I like and it seems clean to me how the urls are structured, here the code:

```
from .views import (
    CouponListView, CouponDetailView, buy_coupon, UserCouponListView, UserCouponDetailView, 
    CouponOfResaleCreateView, CouponOfResaleListView, CouponOfResaleDetailView
) 

from django.urls import path, include

coupon_patterns = ([
    path('', CouponListView.as_view(), name = 'list'),
    path('<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', CouponDetailView.as_view(), name = 'detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/buy/<slug:slug>/', buy_coupon, name = 'buy-coupon'),    

], 'coupon')

user_patterns = ([
    path('', UserCouponListView.as_view(), name = 'list'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', UserCouponDetailView.as_view(), name = 'detail'),

], 'user_coupon')

resale_patterns = ([
    path('', CouponOfResaleListView.as_view(), name = 'list'),
    path('<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', CouponOfResaleDetailView.as_view(), name = 'detail'),
    path('create/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', CouponOfResaleCreateView.as_view(), name = 'create'),

], 'resale')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(coupon_patterns)),
    path('resale/', include(resale_patterns)),
    path('<slug:slug>/', include(user_patterns)),
]
```

So, what do you think of this structure? Is it bad practice? Let me know your opinions, any advice helps my learning.